# NSURLSession prevent authentication challenge for proxy

Tags: objective-c, authentication, proxy, nsurlsession

I am using NSURLSession to implement an osx application that perform REST requests, and has the ability of manually or automatically configure proxy settings for app requests.

I was able to do this using session configuration, and is working for simple contexts.
However when it comes to proxies that require authentication I encounter some issues.

Due to some project requirements, when a request fails due to proxy authentication error(status code 407), I need to display my own custom dialog.

From what I've read so far, I did not find any way of achieving this using NSURLSession. There are some delegate methods related to authentication challenge, but are called **after** the challenge was already displayed to the user.

Is there a way to skip showing an authentication challenge for a NSURLSession request and fail with 407 status code instead?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, neither NSURLConnection nor NSURLSession ask the app to handle 407 responses before displaying that dialog, and there's not a way to change that, short of filing a bug with Apple and convincing them to add that functionality in a future version of iOS or OS X.

For now, I think the best you can probably do is use libcurl to make a "junk" request first, see if it returns a 407, and if so, ask the user to provide new credentials.  It isn't pretty, but it will technically meet your requirements.  :-)

But honestly, the requirements are dubious.  OS X and iOS users don't expect to control proxy settings within an app.  They're normally systemwide behaviors.  As such, trying to control them in the app is questionable.  So if you have any say-so in the matter, you should try to get the requirements changed.